# Cannot open a Juypter Notebook File [Permission Denied]

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

One of my ipynb files isn't opening anymore. Whenever I would try to acccess it on Jupyter Notebook, it would just say :

> Error Loading Notebook
>
> Permission denied: [File name].ipynb

[image]

I can launch the notebook through a julia prompt, and all of my other files are still able to open and work properly, but it's just this file that doesn't work. Moreover, this issue just suddenly arised out of nowhere and all of the sudden I couldn't access  my notebook anymore. I don't know if this is because I perhaps updated my windows and this file in particular crashed and was corrupted. The notebooks displays that this file has a size of 0, I can't clone or duplicate it, and downloading it just downloads a blank file. I should have full control of my folder permissions.

Is this file completely gone? Are there any ideas on how to fix this and recover my file?

Comment: One possible issue is file permissions (I suppose you have checked that already). Another possibility is that you have a disk/file system error. Try using tools like `chdsk` (name depends on the OS). Lastly a file could be at some strange location (eg. very deep and long path, path with strange characters etc.)